# Sending UTF-8 chars C# to C does not work properly

Tags: c#, sqlite, utf-8, com-interop

I work with SQLite for C. I try to send UTF-8 Chars to .dll from c# app but everytime it's work different. For example sometimes it add "değirmenci" and another time with same code it add "değirmencil" but I don't change the word. And sometimes it's adding samething in the UNIQUE column ( I think there is a char but it is not visible like 0x01 in ascii)
Sorry about my English.

This is my c# code;

```
    [DllImport("dllfile.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]

static void Main()
{
    byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("değirmenci");
    int r;
    //
    IntPtr unmanagedPointer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedPointer, bytes.Length);

    IntPtr ch = Tahmin_Baslat();

    r = Sozcuk_Ekle(unmanagedPointer);
    Console.WriteLine(r);
    Console.Read();
    //
}
```

and this is my C code

```
    int Sozcuk_Ekle(const char* kok,int tip_1=1,int tip_2=0,int tip_3=0)
{
    sqlite3 *ch; 
    int rc; 
    char *HataMsj = 0; 

    rc = sqlite3_open(veritabani, &ch); // Veritabanının açılması

    if( rc )
    {
        return HATA_DEGERI;
    }

    char buff[strlen(kok) + 64];
    sprintf(buff,"INSERT INTO kokler (kok,tip_1,tip_2,tip_3) VALUES('%s',%d,%d,%d)",kok,tip_1,tip_2,tip_3); // Verilerin Birleştirilmesi
    sqlite3_exec(ch,buff,GeriBildirim,0,&HataMsj); // Komutun Yürütülmesi
    sqlite3_close(ch); // Veritabanını kaynaklarının serbest bırakılması
    return DOGRU_DEGERI; // Doğru Dönder
}
```

(header files etc. included)
And it is how it goes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ4fE.png

**Solution** 
Adding  NULL terminator to end of the bytes.
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("değirmenci\0"); like this.

Comment: You titled your question "SQLite does not work properly". I am willing to bet that SQLite is working fine, but your code is not working properly. Sorry though, I do not know what the bug in your code is. Note however, it is not clear from your question if your problems are in the `C` code, `C#`, or both. You might clarify that for people.

Comment: @mah thank you I changed title for people and I think it's in the C code but I am not quite sure about it so I cant specify which language is going wrong

Comment: You should check the [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the **DllImport** attribute, I think is **Cdecl**. And also check if you need to add a NULL terminator to your UTF-8 string manually (try something simple like `"değirmenci" + '\0'`).

Comment: @Jigsore I think it solved my problem but I need to test it if it works I edit my post with solution. Thank you by the way, I though they add "\0" automaticly.

Comment: By the way, I was talking about changing this part: `byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("değirmenci" + '\0');`.

Comment: @Jigsore I understood that and it worked perfectly thank you. I am going to change this post.

Comment: @Jigsore post that as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Check [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in the **DllImport** attribute (should be **Cdecl**). And add a NULL terminator to your UTF-8 string:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("değirmenci" + '\0');
```

This will add NULL terminator to the **resulting** UTF-8 string (which is not needed for native .NET strings).